# Index Data from External Database for Search - Views

Tags: views, search

I have a Drupal 7 view which obtains data from an external database and displays it on the page. I would like to index this external data (read through Views) so that the resulting items can be searched for using Drupal Search. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Every thought about Solr?

Comment: I don't know too much about any search methods, so I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: It's rather difficult to implement for the first time and meant for indexing large proportions of data. But it's extremely powerful! How much data are we talking about?

Comment: A couple of million rows for several tables.

Answer (score 0):

Like Michiel said Solr is a good option but is complicated to set up.

Another option is to implement a [Google search server](https://www.google.co.uk/enterprise/search/) that can then be integrated with Drupal using the [Google Search Appliance module](https://drupal.org/project/google_appliance). This is a paid solution but easier to setup.